# Is there an equivalent to Html.Raw in Blazor?

Tags: blazor

I have some HTML that is stored in a string. How can I render it in a Blazor/Razor view without automatic HTML encoding?

Comment: I make this remark in case it is of use to anyone else: if you have a MarkupString? (nullable), you have to cast it to MarkupString (not nullable) in order for it to not be escaped.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Feature to render raw HTML was added in `Blazor` 0.5.0 version. This is the example of how raw HTML can be rendered from `string` containing HTML content:

```
@((MarkupString)myMarkup)

@functions {
    string myMarkup = "<p class='markup'>This is a <em>markup string</em>.</p>";
}
```

More info can be found in ["Blazor 0.5.0 experimental release now available"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-0-5-0-experimental-release-now-available/#render-raw-html) announcement.

Comment: Note that you can use MarkupString to inject a <script> tag into a dynamic Blazor page, something that normally won't be allowed by Blazor. Perhaps it's not what I'm supposed to do, but it's useful if you want to insert a custom Google Search box.

Comment: Beware: MarkupString  is auto-closing tags, so it is not "raw" at all. If you try to output "<div>" the result will be "<div></div>".

Comment: private static MarkupString HtmlRaw(string value)
    {
        return (MarkupString)value;
    }

Comment: @NickKovalsky any suggestion on how to circumvent this?

Comment: Looks like a "no": https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/15746 "Blazor manipulates DOM Elements = element needs to be immediately valid (closed tags)

Answer (score 14):

**Yes**, sample:

```html
@page "/"

<h2>Title</h2>
<hr />
<p>
    @ms
</p>
```

```cs
@code {
    MarkupString ms => (MarkupString)description;

    string description = $@"
This is an example of how Azure serverless functions can be consumed from Blazor WASM.
<br><br>
To run this project in development mode, the <b>HttpTriggerSample</b> project must be run simultaneously.
<br><br>
Serverless Functions origin: <b>{fs}<b>.";

    // by example
    static string fs => Program.IS_DEVELOPMENT ? "DevelopmentStorage" : "Azure";
}
```

Comment: MarkupString  is auto-closing tags, so it is not "raw" at all. If you try to output "<div>" the result will be "<div></div>"

Answer (score 8):

You can also store the raw HTML as string to a variable of type `MarkupString`, then you can use it without casting.

```razor
@myMarkup

@code {
    private MarkupString myMarkup = 
        new MarkupString("<p class='markup'>This is a <em>markup string</em>.</p>");
}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

Not right now, but will have it probably in the next version: [Follow this](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/167).

Workaround (from that issue):

**cshtml**

```
<span ref="Span"></span>

@functions{
    [Parameter] string Content { get; set; }
    private ElementRef Span;

    protected override void OnAfterRender()
    {
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser.Interop.RegisteredFunction.Invoke<bool>("RawHtml", Span, Content);
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<script>
    Blazor.registerFunction('RawHtml', function (element, value) {
        element.innerHTML = value;
        for (var i = element.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var childNode = element.childNodes[i];
            element.parentNode.insertBefore(childNode, element);
        }
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        return true;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
index.html
<div>@((MarkupString)InputString)</div>

@code {
    string InputString = "html code";
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="link-dark">@((MarkupString)(get_user(user_row["user_name"].ToString())))</span>
```