# Display text in Blazor with rich text

Tags: html, blazor, richtext

I am using Blazor with a rich text editor.  When I output text like this:

[image]

It adds quotes around the text and the actual markup is displayed:

[image]

My markup is displayed with quotes, and the actual markup (bold and color) is not displayed. Does anyone know why or how to make this work with Blazor?

Comment: I saw this related question posted on StackOverflow in 2018.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50604366/is-there-an-equivalent-to-html-raw-in-blazor/51585301#51585301

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is fundamental to the way Blazor compiles and renders pages. The components are built as generated classes during compilation that then use a RenderTreeBuilder to generate the HTML back out again. This in turn takes your inputs to be string literals and outputs them as such, as what blazor is seeing in your markup is "insert string x into position y", not actual HTML markup.

**EDIT**
I found a simple way to do this shortly after I answered so I placed it here, using the type `MarkupString`. Setup is done like this:

**MarkupRenderer.razor**

```cs
@((MarkupString)Markup)

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Markup { get; set; }

}
```

and then in your parent you use it like so:

**Parent.razor***

```cs
.....

<MarkupRenderer Markup="@markupString" />
```

This will render out the tags and attributes as you are looking for to get the content output as HTML.

Official documentation on this is very short and includes the warning:
 *"Rendering raw HTML constructed from any untrusted source is a security risk and should be avoided!"*, which it is, so keep that in mind if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using **Markdig**

```
<PackageReference Include="Markdig" Version="0.20.0" />
```

Then including an unmapped field in my POCO model:

```
[NotMapped]
public MarkupString HtmlQuestion { get; set; }
```

Then in my service layer I added the markup text:

```
using Markdig;
...
q.HtmlQuestion = (MarkupString)Markdown.ToHtml(q.QuestionDescription);
```